# Remove all redirects introduced by a WordPress hack

Tags: redirects, wordpress, hacked-site

There is this online scam website that's causing great damage. From the many complaints online, it's obvious that people are losing thousands of dollars every month on the site.

I've decided to stop them by exposing their scam website and warning as many people as possible. I don't want to mention the Website here cos the scammer & hacker are actively tracking me online. He's hacked me several times already. The last time he hacked my website and added a `noindex` tag, I had to delete the entire WordPress site from my cPanel, reinstall it, and then post my articles again.

He's hacked the website again. This time, he added a redirect error to my sitemap that prevents new articles from being indexed.

Does anyone know how I can better protect my website from future attacks? Also, how can I remove all redirects on my website? If I can't do this, I'll have to delete the site and reinstall it all over again. I want a better solution than that. I hope someone can provide a step-by-step explanation of how to remove any redirects on my website.

Finally, I really need a good solution that prevents hacking or at least makes it 100 times more difficult.

Comment: "How do I clean my hacked site" is a huge topic that can't be answered in the space for an answer here.

Comment: Delete, reinstall, make sure you don't use vulnerable plugins.   Consider getting Wordfence or Securi or similar.   Oh, and a decent host who cares about security can help as well.     (As @StephenOstermiller This is a massive topic and I haven't scraped  the tip of the iceberg here.   Advanced admins should, of-course, ignore my advice)

Comment: If you are trying to expose scammers and are being attacked, reach out to me privately.  My company is pretty small, so you should be able to work out how to get in touch by looking at my profile.